Piano pieces, wich maximum note span is considred acceptable for composing?
As a male self trained keyboard player, I can observe that an octave is the maximum finger span I can reach with my pinky and thumb. I have read that individuals with smaller finger span might have trouble to play more that an octave easily.
Which maximum note span is considered acceptable for my composition to be playable by everyone?
Are they other difficulty factors involved?

Related: 1. How (un)comfortable to play are these large chords?, 2. Max acceptable key range in piano chords?

@ElementsInSpace I see the second as a duplicate in fact, with good answers.

Trying to write for literally “everyone” isn’t completely reasonable. Some people have only one hand. I’d suggest narrowing your ideal player by age and ability level and that will help you determine many of the parameters and limits for your compositions.

The vast majority of people of any sex can span an octave. In any case, it's completely acceptable to write music you can play and let others work around their limitations; Rachmaninoff had massive hands and wrote only for himself.
